# Whey do I get error in "snapshot.data.length"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error with the streambuilder in flutter.
I'm not sure why I get this error. Please help me out with this problem.

```
Widget _galleryGrid() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: imageUrlsController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data!.length != 0) {
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: snapshot.data![index],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              )
            );
          }
        );
      } else {
        return Center(child: Text('No images to display.'));
      }
    } else {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }
);
```

}

I have red underline indicating error in 3 parts in total

if (snapshot.data!.**length** != 0) {

itemCount: snapshot.data!.**length**,

imageUrl: snapshot.data![**index**]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what errors messages are showing on screen?

Comment: `return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(`

Comment: thanks Nagual. I tried that and it solved the problem. however I have another error that says "Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety: -package: cached_network_image - package:: flutter_cache_manager". do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
2. Try update your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.12.0 or higher.
3. Running 'pub get'

**OR**

replace this with

```
if (snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by

```
return StreamBuilder<dynamic>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply specify your snapshot type in builder of stream as:-

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnaphot> snapshot) {
```